# Input does not get checked in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, input, checked

I need to find a way on how to sort it out this issue with IE8

I have a table with my columns and rows

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="body">
            <th class="checkbox"><input class="forecast first" name="1" type="checkbox"></th>
            <th class="checkbox"><input class="forecast second" name="2" type="checkbox"></th>
            <th class="checkbox"><input class="forecast third" name="3" type="checkbox"></th>
            <th class="checkbox"><input class="forecast any" name="any" type="checkbox"></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr class="body">
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast first" name="1" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast second" name="2" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast third" name="3" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast any" name="any" type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="body">
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast first" name="1" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast second" name="2" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast third" name="3" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="checkbox"><input class="forecast any" name="any" type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Inside my columns there are my input checkbox which work with the following combinations:

```
oncheck: function(checkbox) {
    if ($(checkbox).prop("checked")) { // checking
      if ($(checkbox).hasClass('first')) {
        $('.forecast[value="' + checkbox.value +'"]').prop("checked", false); // unmarking checkboxes in this row
        $('.forecast.first').prop("checked", false);                          // unmarking checkboxes in this column
        $('.forecast.any').prop("checked", false);                            // unmarking checkboxes in Any order column
        $(checkbox).prop("checked", true);
      }
      if ($(checkbox).hasClass('second')) {
        if ($('.forecast.first[value!="' + checkbox.value + '"]:checked').length > 0 ) {
          $('.forecast.second').prop("checked", false);                                  // unmarking checkboxes in this column
          $('.forecast.third[value="' + checkbox.value +'"]').prop("checked", false);    // unmarking 3rd checkboxes in this row
          $(checkbox).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
          $(checkbox).prop("checked", false);
        }
      }
      if ($(checkbox).hasClass('third')) {
        if ($('.forecast.first[value!="' + checkbox.value + '"]:checked').length > 0 &&
            $('.forecast.second[value!="' + checkbox.value + '"]:checked').length > 0) {
          $('.forecast.third').prop("checked", false); // unmarking checkboxes in this column
          $(checkbox).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
          $(checkbox).prop("checked", false);
        }
      }
      if ($(checkbox).hasClass('any')) {
        // unmarking checkboxes in columns : 1st 2nd 3rd
        $('.forecast.first').prop("checked", false);
        $('.forecast.second').prop("checked", false);
        $('.forecast.third').prop("checked", false);
        $(checkbox).prop("checked", true);
      }
    }
    else {
      if ($(checkbox).hasClass('first')) {
        $('.forecast').prop("checked", false); // unchecking all
      }
      if ($(checkbox).hasClass('second')) {
        $('.forecast.third').prop("checked", false); // unchecking all third class
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This means basically that:

- The input in the second column can be checked only when the input in
  the first column is checked, and the input in the third column can be
  checked only when the input in the second column is checked
- All the input can not be checked in the same row, but only an input
  for row
- When the input any is checked , all the others inputs get unchecked

Everything works well in any browser (Safari, Chrome and IE 10 and 9) a part **from IE8 where i can not check my first input**.

Obviously the problem is coming from the script, i need some tips on how to work around it.

Just for more infos previously instead of `prop` i use `attr` and it was not working at all in IE.

All the recommendations, i thought that maybe i can hack up with some js just for ie8

Comment: You might be using jQuery 2.0.0 which is not supported in oldIE(IE 6, 7 and 8). Please confirm it once.

Comment: no the jquery version is 1.9.2..is that supported?

Comment: No. It should work then. Let me check it.

Comment: maybe it's depending on this bug? http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12458

Comment: That ticket has been closed because it is not a bug. And it has no relation to your problem, too. As @grotori pointed out the problem may be somewhere else in your code. Would you mind sharing the code that attaches the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace the following line:

```
if ($(checkbox).prop("checked")) {
```

with this one?

```
if ($(checkbox).is(":checked")) {
```

Comment: it just does not execute, nothing has changed, it still works in any browser a part from ie8

Comment: Can you post the way you bind the behavior to your checkboxes? (I mean the part before the oncheck: function...)

Comment: there is a long part code, in pvt i can send the page in matter

Comment: Don't need the page, no worries. I wanted to see which selector do you use in order to bind the oncheck function. You should put alert on first line of your function to see at least if it gets called. If not, I guess the binding failed or skipped your checkboxes.

Comment: yeah, it skips my checkboxes..maybe i have to rewrite the if conditions for ie8..i dont know

Comment: Ok, then the problem is not on the code snippet you posted but on the part that assigns this behavior to you checkbox. You must "play" with the binding selectors.

Comment: I mean that the code that selects on which checkboxes should assign this behavior to, is not working. You should try finding out how that code finds the checkboxes. For example, it might use a jQuery selector that doesn't work on IE8.